# WPF combobox entlib validation problem

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, enterprise-library

I'm using entlib 5.0 to validate my form. I have some problems with combobox control:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbRs" ItemsSource="{Binding PP.ListRs}" 
          SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding PP.R, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
          Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Databinding to generic list in class PP is working fine. This is class property for selectedValue (public class PP : IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged):

```
[NotNullValidator(MessageTemplateResourceName="R", MessageTemplateResourceType=typeof(Messages))]
    public String R
    {
        get { return _R; }
        set { _R = value; OnPropertyChanged("R"); }
    }
```

The problem is that when I choose value from combobox error indicator doesn't disappear. The property R is set (visible from console), and the submit button is enabled.

This is the resources part of my form:

```
<eFINp:frmDialogBase.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationErrorTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="24" Text="*" ToolTip="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}"/>
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ValidationErrorTemplate}"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ValidationErrorTemplate}"/>
    </Style>
</eFINp:frmDialogBase.Resources>
```

Textbox and passbox controls are working fine.

Comment: If I user devexpress comboboxedit there isn't problem. Maybe because it use own error indicator. So I think the problem is in control template or style.